# How to know if air is trapped at the high point of a piping system

Tags: piping

I have a piping system (in my case, a heat exchanger) with several high points, currently in operation. The HX was filled "pressure less" (one side open) and is now supplied by a heating system at about 2.5 bar - so it is possible that remaining air was compressed enough to allow operation, but is still present. There are no vents etc. in place.

Is there a somewhat reliable way to know if and how much air is trapped in these high points? Is noise a reliable indicator? Are there others?

The piping is DN100, flow velocity should be up to around 1 m/s.

Comment: There are automatic bleed valves available - check that they match the conditions.

Comment: Noise can be caused by a lot of factors and is not a good indicator of a single one unless you can eliminate the others.  What fluid and operating temperatures?

Comment: Water, approx 70°C

Comment: It's a good question.  I had a Nissan-built car that had a super-complicated venting procedure for filling the cooling system, other cars that just work.  I feel like you either design it right or you don't.

Comment: tbh we designed it wrong and now try to minimize damage. Which includes finding out how big the problem actually is ...